# Microsoft Powerpoint addin to insert a slide

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, add-in, office-js

Want to create a microsoft powerpoint addin to insert a new slide.

I went through the official documentation

- https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-powerpoint-or-word?product=powerpoint
- https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document?product=powerpoint

did not get anything meaningful.

Any reference and pointers are most welcome :) .

Comment: I need to write addin.

Comment: There are several types of add-ins you can use in PowerPoint and several ways of writing them.  Your links all point to javascript/html add-ins.  Is it necessary to use these for some reason?  .NET or VBA add-ins are far more capable.

Comment: I am JS developer, would prefer JS base addin :)

Comment: Understood.  But that being the case, I can't help.  Someone else can, I hope.